# Logging and Saving a workout on Apple Watch when away from iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos

In my workout app, my users are typically away from their iPhone during their workout.  I understand that with the new Series 3 Apple Watch + LTE this isn't an issue, however for Series 0 through Series 3 (WIFI only), does Apple take care of logging the data on the watch, and more importantly if my user saves his/her data into HealthKit with no WIFI available and the iPhone out of reach will it sync up and save the workout when the iPhone is back within range?  If not, what can I do avoid losing user workout data other than not permitting a save to be available unless the iPhone is within range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your data is stored in HealthKit, you don’t need to worry about this. HealthKit data will sync when the devices are connected.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data in the documents directory just like on the iphone and synch it when the phone is available.  Apple has documentation on all the ways you can share data [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html).  For instance you can use [transferFile(_:metadata:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615667-transferfile) to send your watch file over to the phone int he background.

Comment: Thank you!  I have done sharing between the Watch and iPhone before, my question first though was is it necessary?  It seems like this would be sort of a common problem for any outdoor workout app that I would think Apple would build into Healthkit?   But from your answer it sounds like you are saying no?